# Why do the eigenvalues of $A^TB$ equal the nonzero eigenvalues of $AB^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given two matrices, $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ where $m>n$, why do the eigenvalues of $A^TB$ equal the nonzero eigenvalues of $AB^T$?  Essentially, why do the eigenvalues of the inner product between matrices equal the nonzero eigenvalues of the outer product between two matrices?

Comment: @Stefan They may be related, but the question here is more directed and we have a better answer below.  The question should not be flagged.

Comment: you are right, the answer given here is better.

Comment: There are many similar questions, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2061035/eigenvalues-of-ab-and-ba-the-same), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124888/are-the-eigenvalues-of-ab-equal-to-the-eigenvalues-of-ba-citation-needed) and [more](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378303/show-ab-and-ba-have-the-same-eigenvalues).

Comment: @A.Γ.Right on that and the second link looks good.  Thanks for the references.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\lambda\ne0$, and $x\ne 0$, such that
$$
AB^Tx=\lambda x,
$$
then
$$
B^TAy=B^TA(B^Tx)=\lambda B^Tx=\lambda y.
$$
Clearly, $y=B^Tx\ne 0$, otherwise, $AB^Tx=0$, as well, and hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B^TA$.

Answer (score 1):

When $A$ and $B$ are square matrices, $AB$ and $BA$ have the same
characteristic polynomial and so the same eigenvalues.

When $A$ and $B$ are $m\times n$ and $n\times m$ ($m<n$), let $A'$ and $B'$
be the matrices got by appending extra zero rows to $A$ and $B$.
Then $B'A'=BA$ and $A'B'$ is  the diagonal sum of $AB$ with a zero matrix.
So the eigenvalues of $AB$ are those of $BA$ plus $n-m$ extra zeros.

Applying to the problem in hand $A^TB$ and $BA^T$ have the same
eigenvalues except for some zeros. But the eigenvalues of a matrix
are not changed by transposition. So $(BA^T)^T=AB^T$ has
the same eigenvalues as $BA^T$ etc.

Comment: $A′$ and $B′$ be the matrices got by appending extra zero **rows** to $A$ and $B$? Isn't columns of $B$ correct?